# marquee bar in html

Tags: html, marquee

I want to align one image then marquee and then another image in one line but the last image always shift to next line.
I am using the following code:

```
<input type="image" src="../images/arrleft.png" height="30px" width="30px" id="left" style="float:left"/>

<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrolldelay="100" style="float:none">
//image scrolling
</marquee>

<input type="image" src="../images/arrright.png" height="30px" width="30px" id="right" style="float:right" />
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: @JeremyD: OP just didn't format it. Fixed.

Comment: FYI, most people consider `marquee` to border on "evil" only slight less than Comic Sans or a `goto` statement. :) Just bear that in mind if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try floating the `<marquee>` to the `left`. It's probably a `block` element.

Or make it `inline-block`:

```
marquee {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, the `<marquee>` tag isn't a standard HTML tag and is only implemented for the sake of compatibility in most browsers. Try using a JavaScript solution instead.